# How to identify an embedded palindrome within an array of digits

Tags: arrays, c, palindrome, function-definition

Say we have

```
int arr1[]={1,2,3,4,5};
int temp1[], temp2[];
```

and that we need to copy the first 3 members from arr1 to temp1, and the second 3 from arr1 to temp2, so that

```
temp1={1,2,3};
temp2={2,3,4};
```

and so on and so forth, how would you go on about doing it? I am trying to write a program to check if a user inputted number contains a palindrome in a length k (where k is also chosen by the user) and my idea was to store the number in an array, take the first 3 members, put them in an array, reverse them and put that in another array and then compare, but I am stuck on how to solve the problem I mentioned above, I tried something like:

```
void copyandReverse(int arr[], int copy[], int reverse[], int start, int length)
{
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        copy[start+i]=arr[start+i];
        reverse[start+i]=arr[start+length-i-1];

    }
}
```

but it seems to only copy the first 3 elements, and reverse them.

PS: I don't think we're allowed to use string or dynamic memory allocation, it's given that the inputted number contains less then 10 digits, so I made the temporary arrays with a constant size 10.

Comment: You don't need arrays to check for palindrome.  Just loop through the array with two indexes, one going forwards and the other one backward.  Break when you get a mismatch.

Comment: As an aside, `int temp1[], temp2[];` is not a legal declaration.  The arrays either need to have an initializer:  `int temp[] = {1,2,3,4,5}`, or a size:  `int temp[5] = {0};`.  In the second example, the initializer is optional, but recommended.

Comment: Are you suggesting then that the following input from a user:  `001234432664`, because the 4th through 9th digits form a palindrome, that the array would satisfy your  requirement?, and that you want to test for an embedded palindrome this in code?

Comment: @rykker yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to achieve, although an important note is that if a 0 is inserted into the number on the left, then we ignore it like a normal number, but if a zero is part of the palindrome, then you have to print it, which is why I tried to copy everything into an array

Comment: _" I don't think we're allowed to use string or"_...  I get not being allowed to use dynamic memory allocation, but If you are reading user input from `stdin`, the data comes in as a string, either read into a buffer using eg, `fgets()` or `scanf()`, of if on a command line entry, `argv[x]`, so please confirm why you think that.

Comment: That's quite the XY. Are you sure you don't mean to ask how to check if user input is a palindrome?

Comment: @Joshua I'll try to explain a little more, if a user inputs 30102, with a length of 3, then we must return 010 because it is a palindrome of length 3, take that same number but with length of 2, and the answer is that there isn't a palindrome within that satisfies the requirement.

Comment: The question is clear enough, you want to find embedded palindromes within a given string of digits, eg. [Best Way To Find A Palindrome In A Given String](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-find-palindrome-in-a-given-string-effective-way) (but not in C)

Comment: Your title is basically a distraction from what you are really trying to get help with.  It should be something like ***How to identify an embedded  palindrome within an array of digits.***.  Do not suggest the method unless the method is a requirement.

Comment: Are you allowed to use other non-typical forms of array creation?  eg since `C99`, [VLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) have been available.

Comment: @ryyker It compiles just fine that way on my computer, but not on the server where it'll be checked, sadly

Comment: VLA or the link I posted in the previous comment?

Comment: VLA, the link works just fine but I'm not sure I fully understand the concept in there.

Comment: It allows you to create an array of a specified size based on information obtained during runtime.  i.e. if user inputs a 3 from a call to `scanf()`, and you have stored that into a variable say `int val`, you can do:  `int array[val] = {0};` to make an array of size 3.

Comment: As I explained in my comment above, a user inputs a random number, eg, 20103, and a length k, eg length=3, the program should check if any subsequence of the number contains a palindrome that is 3 digits long, in this case, 010, and prints it. If the input is 20103, but with a length of 2, then no subsequence that contains 2 digits is a palindrome, another example, 1123, with a length of 2, then 11 is a palindrome made of 2 digits, that is contained within the subsequence

Comment: @ryyker yeah like I said, it works on my computer, but when I run it on the server it gives me a variable length array error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no any need to create auxiliary arrays to check whether a given array is a palindrome.

This can be done much simpler.

Write a function like this

```
int is_palindrome( const unsigned int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while (i < n / 2 && a[i] == a[n - i - 1]) ++i;

    return i == n / 2;
}
```

then in main if you have an array like

```
unsigned int a[10];
```

and you need to check whether a sub-array with three elements is a palindrome then you can do this in a for loop

```
size_t k = 3;

for ( size_t i = 0; i <= 10 - k; i++ )
{
    if ( is_palindrome( a + i, k ) ) 
    {
        printf( "The sub-array at position %zu:", i );
        for ( size_t j = i; j < k + i; j++ ) printf( " %u", a[j] );
        puts( " is a palindrome" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as @stark mentioned, just iterate over the array with two indices.
Please see an example implementation below. You just need to evaluate the actual size from the userinput before you validate it.

The code below assumes `0` as the delimited. After gathering the actual user input size, we start a loop with index `i` and `j`. Looping until they have swapped positions.

If a mismatch exists, we return `FALSE`, otherwise `TRUE`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

size_t getUserInputLength(int *arr, size_t len)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    if (arr[i] == 0)
    {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return len;
}

int checkPalindrome(int *arr, size_t len)
{
  size_t i, j;
  for (i = 0, j = len - 1; i <= j; i++, j--)
  {
    printf("Current indices: [i: %ld, j: %ld]\n", i, j);
    printf("Current values: [i: %d, j: %d]\n", arr[i], arr[j]);
    if (arr[i] != arr[j])
    {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
  return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
  // even number of user input
  int evenInput[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0};
  size_t evenLen = getUserInputLength(evenInput, 10);
  printf("Even number returned: %d\n", checkPalindrome(evenInput, evenLen));

  // odd number of user input
  int oddInput[] = {1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  size_t oddLen = getUserInputLength(oddInput, 10);
  printf("Odd number returned: %d\n", checkPalindrome(oddInput, oddLen));

  return 0;
}
```